# When does the storage allocation takes place in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, storage

```
class A
{
public:
A() {}
};

A b;     //global variable

void fun(void)
{
A a;
}

int main()
{
fun();
}
```

In this code, I have 2 questions (UPDATED)

1. When does the storage for object a allocated, when the fun() is called in main() i.e. at runtime or at the compile time?
2. For global variable b, when storage will be allocated for it and when its constructor will be called?

Comment: at compile time nothing of your code is ever allocated, only at run time. In your code example, the compiler optimizes everything away: no object `A` is ever allocated.

Comment: @Luv - To let you in on the joke: Ask yourself, what do we see when your program is run? Nothing! So perhaps the compiler optimizes it to just `int main(){}`, and no objects are created at all. We can't tell, because there is no output from the program (hint!).

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a local variable allocated in the body of `fun()`.  An `A` is instantiated every time you call `fun()`, and then it is de-instantiated (destroyed, destructor called) when the object falls out of scope -- which in this case is when `fun()` returns.

`A`'s constructor is called when the object is instantiated.

None of this happens at compile-time.

Comment: In reference to storage allocation for object a, isn't this compiler dependent?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Luv: Under the as-if rule for optimization, it's even compiler-setting dependent. You can't observe where and when `A a` is allocated, given your definition of `class A`. That allows maximum optimization flexibility, including not allocation `a` at all.